# Inner Product and projection

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

V is in inner product space over F and U is subspace.
$p=P_u(v)$.
I need to prove or disprove by an example that:

1. $||v||=||p||$
2. $<v,p>=<p,p>$

Comment: You need to prove/disprove, we need your attempt.

Comment: What inner product spaces come to mind?

Comment: I dont know where to start so can u please guide me? im not looking for solution

Comment: I _am_ guiding: what inner product spaces do you know?

Comment: can you help me in what ||p|| is??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: ad 1. What do you know about $\ker P_U$? Can a $v\in\ker P_U$ fulfill 1.?

ad 2. What does it mean for $P_U$ to be an *orthogonal* projection? Can you say something about $P_U(v-p)$?

Comment: didnt understand for 1...